# C++ Compile Error (comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions)

Tags: c++

I need help regarding to this message:

> char_cards.cpp: In member function 'void CHARACTER::Cards_pullout()':
>   char_cards.cpp:88: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned
>   integer expressions

Can somone explain what this error means? I think the problem is with DWORD but i don't know what is wrong.

This is the function:

```
DWORD CHARACTER::GetEmptySpaceInHand()
{
    for (int i=0; i<MAX_CARDS_IN_HAND; ++i)
    {
        if (character_cards.cards_in_hand[i].type == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
void CHARACTER::Cards_pullout()
{
    DWORD empty_space = GetEmptySpaceInHand(); 
    if (empty_space == -1) // Here is the error.
    {
        #ifdef __MULTI_LANGUAGE_SYSTEM__
        ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_INFO, LC_TEXT(GET_LANGUAGE(this), "You don't have space in hands."));
        #else
        ChatPacket(CHAT_TYPE_INFO, LC_TEXT("You don't have space in hands."));
        #endif
        return;
    }
    RandomizeCards();
    SendUpdatedInformations();
}
```

Comment: What part of the warning do you not understand?

Comment: Assuming that line 88 is the one with the `if` statement and the comparison expression, remember that `DWODRD` is an *unsigned* type. Comparing an unsigned and a singed type will not work very well (since the unsigned type can never have negative values).

Comment: So i mush check for if (empty_space == 0) ?

Comment: @FrezyFrezy It depends on what `GetEmptySpaceInHand` is returning, and what you actually want to test for.

Comment: This is the function for GetEmptySpaceInHand

Comment: Why did you choose `DWORD` as a return type instead of `int`?

Comment: I forgot is not signed .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initializing an unsigned integer to `-1` is well defined and sets the unsigned integer to its maximal value. So using -1 to represent an error condition is OK. To get rid of the warning, you have  few options:

1) Use a `static_cast`. This indicates that you are aware of the conversion and it is intentional:

```
if empty_space == static_cast<DWORD>(-1)) { ...
```

2) Use `std::numeric_limits<DWORD>::max()` instead of `-1`. This will require including the `limits` header.

```
if (empty_space == std::numeric_limits<DWORD>::max()) { ...
```